# Stationarity and structural breaks in STAR models

Tags: time-series, econometrics, autoregressive

I have two theory questions about Smooth Transition Autoregressive Models that I can't seem to answer conclusively from reading the literature.

It seems to me that a time series that switches regimes smoothly could well appear to have a unit root or a structural break by definition.

1. Do the models (LSTAR and ESTAR for example) require stationary data?
2. Must I test for structural breaks before estimating?